# FPDF add button to back

Tags: php, html, fpdf

It's a simple question.

I've generated a PDF from the data in a form, with the FPDF library.

I would like a back button back to the form that created the FPDF, not having to make a step back manually (with the button on the browser) and the back is returned to form with full fields.

You can add a button to the output generated library?

I tried to write code after the code html php, but got no results, and does not work to write HTML code embedded with php.

Thanks!

Comment: No. The PDF is a document which is downloaded and shown. It is not an HTML page, and can't contain scripts that navigate.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. You want a web back button in a PDF document? You can't really do that. You could store the information the user has entered in a cookie though and fill it in again next time they go to the page.

Comment: Yes, simply have a button to return to the index of my project where the form is empty. I had read that it was not possible but there is always brilliant minds that can achieve all..

Comment: You can add a link to a PDF with no problems. http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto6.htm

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution:

```
$pdf->Image("_images/logo.png",8,11.3,73,0,"","index.php");
```

Thanks!